# MYSQL - function not returning expected results

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm building a site for property rentals. I'm doing the search bit now and I'm trying to setup a function I can call for each property. The function needs to grab all rows from the `rental_periods` table attached to a given property then work out the best (cheapest) weekly price.

I have the following tables setup already.

`properties` - One line for each property

`rental_periods` - Multiple lines for each property, tied with id.

Each line is `selfcatered` or `catered`.

If `selfcatered` the price needs to be worked out from prices given in:

- WeekDayPerDay - `wdpd`
- WeekEndPerNight - `wepn`
- Monthly price - `monthly`
- Week price - `wk`

If `catered` the prices can be given in:

- PerPersonPerNight - `pppn`
- PerNight - `pn`
- PerPersonPerWeek - `pppw`

I need a function that takes a property id and then grabs all periods that apply, then depending on selfcatered/catered works out the price per week that's best.

What I've got so far doesn't seem to be working. It either returns NULL or returns 100000.00 (my upper limit default price).

Here's the code

```
DELIMITER $$


CREATE FUNCTION get_price(myid INT)
  RETURNS VARCHAR(20)

BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE price decimal(30,3) default 100000.000;

    DECLARE id INT;
    DECLARE prop_id INT;
    DECLARE type enum('catered','selfcatered');
    DECLARE name varchar(45);

    DECLARE `from` date;
    DECLARE `to` date;

    DECLARE currency varchar(45);
    DECLARE so tinyint;
    DECLARE wk decimal(30,3);
    DECLARE wepn  decimal(30,3);

    DECLARE wdpd  decimal(30,3);
    DECLARE monthly  decimal(30,3);
    DECLARE extra  decimal(30,3);
    DECLARE pppn  decimal(30,3);
    DECLARE pn  decimal(30,3);

    DECLARE pppw  decimal(30,3);
    DECLARE minstay int;
    DECLARE maxstay int;
    DECLARE breakfast varchar(45);  
    DECLARE annual TINYINT;

    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM rental_periods WHERE prop_id = myid;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    OPEN cur1;

    REPEAT
    FETCH cur1 INTO id, prop_id, type, name, `from`, `to`, currency, so, wk, wepn, wdpd, minstay, maxstay, monthly, extra, pppn, pn, pppw, breakfast, annual;

    IF NOT done THEN
        IF (@type = "selfcatered") THEN
            IF (@wdpd > 0 AND (@wdpd * 7) < @price) THEN
                SET price = @wdpd * 7;
            END IF;

            IF (@wepn > 0 AND (@wepn * 7) < @price) THEN
                SET price = @wepn * 7;
            END IF;

            IF ((@wdpd > 0 AND @wepn > 0) AND
            (@wdpd * 5 + @wepn * 2) < @price) THEN
                SET price = @wdpd * 5 + @wepn * 2;
            END IF;

            IF (@monthly > 0 AND (@monthly / (52 / 12)) < @price) THEN
                SET price = @monthly / (52 / 12);
            END IF;

            IF (@wk > 0 AND @wk < @price) THEN
                SET price = @wk;
            END IF;
        ELSE
            IF (@pppn > 0 AND (@pppn * 7) < @price) THEN
                SET price = @pppn * 7;
            END IF;

            IF (@pn > 0 AND (@pn * 7) < @price) THEN
                SET price = @pn * 7;
            END IF;

            IF (@pppw > 0 AND (@pppw) < @price) THEN
                SET price = @pppw;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END IF;
    UNTIL done END REPEAT;

    CLOSE cur1;

    RETURN price;
END $$
```

i'm hoping/not thats it's something stupid with how I've arranged it, or my lack of pure MySQL.

ANY help would be very helpful.

EDIT:

Here's an example row from `rental_periods`:

```
INSERT INTO `rental_periods` (`id`, `prop_id`, `type`, `name`, `from`, `to`, `currency`, `so`, `wk`, `wepn`, `wdpd`, `minstay`, `maxstay`, `monthly`, `extra`, `pppn`, `pn`, `pppw`, `breakfast`, `annual`) 
VALUES (64732, 32, 'selfcatered', 'Summer', '2012-06-01', '2012-08-31', NULL, 1, '350', '60', '100', '', '', '', '', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0);
```

I'd expect the function to return `350` picked from the per week column. However if the `wepn` was 30, not 60, I'd expect `210` to come back (worked out from 7 * wepn prices).

The code im testing in SP:

```
DELIMITER $$


CREATE procedure tmp_get_price(myid INT)

 BEGIN

    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;


    DECLARE price decimal(30,3) default 100000.000;


    DECLARE id INT;
    DECLARE prop_id INT;
    DECLARE type enum('catered','selfcatered');
    DECLARE name varchar(45);

    DECLARE `from` date;
    DECLARE `to` date;

    DECLARE currency varchar(45);
    DECLARE so tinyint;
    DECLARE wk decimal(30,3);
    DECLARE wepn  decimal(30,3);

    DECLARE wdpd  decimal(30,3);
    DECLARE monthly  decimal(30,3);
    DECLARE extra  decimal(30,3);
    DECLARE pppn  decimal(30,3);
    DECLARE pn  decimal(30,3);

    DECLARE pppw  decimal(30,3);
    DECLARE minstay int;
    DECLARE maxstay int;
    DECLARE breakfast varchar(45);  
    DECLARE annual TINYINT;



    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id, prop_id, type, name, `from`, `to`, currency, so, wk, wepn, wdpd, minstay, maxstay, monthly, extra, pppn, pn, pppw, breakfast, annual FROM rental_periods WHERE prop_id = myid;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    OPEN cur1;


    REPEAT
    FETCH cur1 INTO id, prop_id, type, name, `from`, `to`, currency, so, wk, wepn, wdpd, minstay, maxstay, monthly, extra, pppn, pn, pppw, breakfast, annual;


    IF NOT done THEN
    IF (type = "selfcatered") THEN

        IF (wdpd > 0 AND (wdpd * 7) < price) THEN
            SET price = wdpd * 7;
        END IF;


        IF (wepn > 0 AND (wepn * 7) < price) THEN
            SET price = wepn * 7;
        END IF;


        IF ((wdpd > 0 AND wepn > 0) AND
            (wdpd * 5 + wepn * 2) < price) THEN
            SET price = wdpd * 5 + wepn * 2;
        END IF;


        IF (monthly > 0 AND (monthly / (52 / 12)) < price) THEN
            SET price = monthly / (52 / 12);
        END IF;


        IF (wk > 0 AND wk < price) THEN
            SET price = wk;
        END IF;
    ELSE
        IF (pppn > 0 AND (pppn * 7) < price) THEN
            SET price = pppn * 7;
        END IF;

        IF (pn > 0 AND (pn * 7) < price) THEN
            SET price = pn * 7;
        END IF;

        IF (pppw > 0 AND (pppw) < price) THEN
            SET price = pppw;
        END IF;
    END IF;


    END IF;
    UNTIL done END REPEAT;

    CLOSE cur1;

    select price;
END $$
```

still doesnt work... :( am i being stupid... cant see why this wont work..?!?
gets the periods...
goes throught each one...
if the price is less set it....
select price....?!?

if i put multiple selects in... for example inside the cursor.
only the very bottom one fires and returns 100000.000

i've setup all the value fields as decimals and not allowing NULL...

any thoughts when im going wrong...? also tried debug by inserting in to log table... never fires..?!

Comment: When I'm having issues figuring out the path my stored procedures are taking, I add `PRINT (1,2,3,etc)` statements in the control flow, as well as printing out the values of certain variables along the way. This might help in the future. (For MySQL, you should be able to `SELECT (1,2,3)`.)

Comment: Check to make sure the columns from your cursor are aligned with your variables. You might want to name each column instead of using 'select *'. --> and do what @AdamV said <--

Comment: Can you give us an example row of data, along with what you expect it to return, so we can walk it through your procedure and see why it doesn't match?

Comment: Is `price` the same variable as `@price`? Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm just not familiar with these MySQL nuances.

Comment: its meant to be... i'm not 110% on MySQL which is the real issue... i think '@price' to get data and 'price' to sert data....!??! i played with these and still didnt fix it.... (i copied a set procedure and thats what they seamed to do... :(   )

Comment: I'm walking through your sample row and I think you're right, it would return $350. However, I see two possibilities: a) the cursor keeps going and finds a different row that's returning $0; or b) one of your empty string/null values is treated incorrectly and causes `price` to go to zero. I'd try putting debugging-type statements in there to write out things like `SELECT 'Setting price to ' + price ' for @pn calculation'`

Comment: got rid of all those stupid `@` and still no good... :( just comes back with 100000.00 no matter what prop...

Comment: can i write a select in there...? comes back as errors wont run... can u have SELECT in function.?? tried inserting into another `log` table and that doesnt work either...?!! :(

Comment: @PhilPoore, if necessary, copy the function into a stored procedure and run it from there for testing. There shouldn't be any problems having multiple `SELECT` statements in a SP.

Comment: i've put it in a SP, and... no joy..! multiple selects the last one only shows... im thinking there might be something up with the cursor bit, nothing inside is getting done....?!? :(

Comment: @PhilPoore: I don't have enough experience with cursors (or honestly, even MySQL) to give you additional information on that. If you want to be sure the cursor is picking up all the data you expect it to, you could erase everything inside the `FETCH/REPEAT` and replace it with a `SELECT` to print out all the data it's picking up.

Comment: i'm gunna mark this as answered... the answer is i need to read ALOT more about MySQL esp Cursors...!!! :( thanks @AdamV youve been helpfull....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to read more on cursors this seams a good place to start...

http://www.kbedell.com/2009/03/02/a-simple-example-of-a-mysql-stored-procedure-that-uses-a-cursor/

Comment: The `prop_id = myid` was using the user variable not prop_id from the select... put in rental_periods.prop_id and it worked as expected...!!!!

Comment: In my opinion this must be posted in your answer and the answer accepted (just as you were planning). For this is something that experienced MySQL developers just *had* to spot. For their sakes, let us think they just weren't around. :)